# Bogus Method Descriptor in Android JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I have the following class in Java

```
package com.artifex.mupdf.data;

public class FzTextSpan {

FzRect bbox;
int len, cap;
FzTextChar[] mFzTextChars;
public FzTextSpan(FzRect bbox, int len, int cap, FzTextChar[] mFzTextChars) {
    super();
    this.bbox = bbox;
    this.len = len;
    this.cap = cap;
    this.mFzTextChars = mFzTextChars;
}
}
```

I am trying to invoke the constructor from JNI using the foll code

```
jclass         jFzSpanClass;
jmethodID      jFzSpanCtor;

jFzSpanClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/artifex/mupdf/data/FzTextSpan");
if (jFzSpanClass==NULL) return NULL;
jFzSpanCtor =  (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jFzSpanClass, "<init>",
   "(Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzRect;II;[Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzTextChar;)V");
```

I am getting

```
 Bogus Method Descriptor:        "(Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzRect;II;[Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzTextChar;)V");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the method signature string wrong. Don't try to guess these: `javap -s` will tell you with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @slaadvak More precisely `javap -s com.artifex.mupdf.data.FzTextSpan` in the directory containing `com.`

Answer (score 1):

You have one semicolon more in the descriptor:

```
"(Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzRect;II;[Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzTextChar;)V"
```

the correct string is:

```
"(Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzRect;II[Lcom/artifex/mupdf/data/FzTextChar;)V"
```